# Error in DataGridView Filter

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, filtering

I fill My Datagridview by using Linq Query in C#. I want to filter this datagridview using a Textbox.

The code of Textbox changed event is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt = (DataTable)(dataGridViewX4.DataSource);

dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("T_P = '{0}'", Txt_T_P_Se.Text);

dataGridViewX4.DataSource = dt;
```

After running the program, this error appears:

Invalid Cast Exception Was Unhandled. Any help in understanding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

my DataSource is :

var Query=
(from p in QcGerdBaf.Taghes where p.QGI_Id_Fk == QGI_Id_Selected select new { p.T_P, p.T_Id });

dataGridViewX4.DataSource = Query.ToList();

Comment: On which line exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

```
int value;  
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
dt = (DataTable)(dataGridViewX4.DataSource);   
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("T_P = {0}",int.TryParse(Txt_T_P_Se.Text, out value));   
dataGridViewX4.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: See the difference near {0}

Comment: I Try this, But same Error received.

Comment: @Erfani I have updated solution please check with that

Answer (score 0):

Try like so, just edit info.

```
(dataGridViewX4.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ID = '{0}'", Txt_T_P_Se.Text);
```

erase your code, and this should work.

```
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//dt = (DataTable)(dataGridViewX4.DataSource);

//dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("T_P = '{0}'", Txt_T_P_Se.Text);

//dataGridViewX4.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: hi
thanks for your attention
i try your code, but same error received.